# unable to loop observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

store.select('books') is an Observable  , and "STEP 1" in below code prints

```
 { "books": [ { "id": 1, "title": "title here1", "description": "desc here1", "author": "test", "price": 99 }, { "id": 2, "title": "title here2", "description": "desc here2", "author": "test", "price": 99 } ] }
```

Now , I would like to loop through books array , and for that I have written "STEP 2" , but it does not print any things.
What needs to be modified to make the *ngFor work?

```
<!-- STEP 1 -->
{{store.select('books') | async | json}} 


 <!-- STEP 2 -->
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let book of store.select('books').books | async">
        {{book.title}} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; {{book.price}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: try this: `let book of (store.select('books') | async)?.books`

Comment: yes , it has worked ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
let book of (store.select('books') | async)?.books
```

because your `store.select('books')` is an `async` process not `store.select('books').books`.

i put `?` after to make sure the response of this statement is not `falsy` value.